# No keyboard backlighting

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 14.10, backlight, keyboard-backlight

I have bought an MS-industral Fusion keyboard.The keyboard supports backlighting and I have tested it on my friends Windows 7 and it worked.I am using Ubuntu 14.10 and backlighting does not work.All the multimedia keys do work.

Backlighting control is actually on the same key as scroll lock and that also does not seem to work.

The only reason I bought this keyboard is because of backlighting.It is helpful for late night programming,gaming and text writing sessions.

Edit:
I tested it on Openmandriva and Kali Linux right now and it does not work.
I also tested it on the alpha/beta Ubuntu desktop next with unity8(15.04) and it worked.When I pressed the button it also activated scroll lock.So maybe if we fix scroll lock.

Edit2:It also works during boot time all the way until the login screen appears.
Ediit3:It also works during shutdown.However I noticed if I use it during boot or shutdown it can hang the whole system.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my answer here in this link:
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/262205

Comment: that's a link not an answer

Comment: Please do not post answers depending on external links. Put the relevant part into your answer (or post the link as a comment to the question if you have enough reputation). See [answer] for details.

Answer (score 14):

Open Terminal then type:

```
xset led
```

enter, and see the magical happen!

Comment: for turn off keyboard backlight, just type
"xset led off" on terminal ubuntu

Comment: thx great ! (worth an alias in bashrc)

Comment: actually `xset led` is disabling numpad on my keyboard -> `xset led 3` it is in my case at least

Comment: @mikakun: oh, thanks, I just figure it out, xset led 3 turn on my keyboard backlight and my numpad working perfectly, thanks

Comment: "xset led" turned my numpad into a joystick!!

Answer (score 5):

Run this command in termial (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'
```

However, you have to do that each time you open a session.

Therefore, I suggest you define this command as a startup application, so that it's run automatically upon login
:)

Comment: THE BEST! Works **as a switch!** + does **NOT** turn off the num lock! - perfect solution :) !

Comment: Strange thing - even though all the keys seem to work in a "regular" places, like browser, file explorer, etc., they are not working in a video player x) guess that's a minor issue though

Answer (score 0):

For my Lenovo Thinkpad using Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04 , just use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle keyboard backlight.

Answer (score -1):

xset led named "Scroll Lock" to turn on

xset -led named "Scroll Lock" to turn off