# Keyboard with RGB that requires a Windows program to light up

Tags: drivers, keyboard, windows, laptop, hardware

I have a Lenovo Y720 that has a backlit keyboard. However, Lenovo choose to not have the light built into the actual firmware, but instead make it dependant on a program called Lenovo Nerve Sense, which is not open source and only runs on Windows.
So far I used to boot up Windows on my PC, run the program, and then boot into Ubuntu. The keyboard light would stay as long as I never turned the laptop off (suspend is fine). This makes me think that the keyboard light runs in the RAM. This solution however is very tiring as I can never shut the laptop off or I would have to boot Windows up again.
I know that a virtual machine does not have access to the hardware and therefore running the program in a VM does not work, the same thing goes for Wine.

So my question is, is there any possible way that I could actually run this program on Ubuntu so my keyboard light can turn on?

I have searched the web for 2 years, asked multiple questions and tried all of the solutions I could find, no solution works, as all of the solutions I have seen are for laptops that have the light built into the firmware and therefore a command like "xset led 3" works, but not for me.

Here is a list of what I have tried:

- https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Gaming-Laptops/Y720-linux-keyboard-backlight/td-p/3763992
- https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/Legion-Y720-Keyboard-backlight-not-working-on-Ubuntu-Linux/m-p/3744635
- https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Gaming-Laptops/Lenovo-Y720-keyboard-backlight-on-linux/td-p/4131177
- https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Gaming-Laptops/Lenovo-Y720-legion-laptop-ubuntu-keyboard-light/td-p/4067288
- [Lenovo Legion Y720 laptop Keyboard backlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031547/lenovo-legion-y720-laptop-keyboard-backlight)
- [Lenovo Legion Y720 keyboard backlights not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014927/lenovo-legion-y720-keyboard-backlights-not-working)
- [Keyboard backlight not working Lenovo Legion Y720](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195229/keyboard-backlight-not-working-lenovo-legion-y720)
- [How to enable keyboard backlight for Ubuntu 18.04 OS on Lenovo Thinkpad L480 laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115644/how-to-enable-keyboard-backlight-for-ubuntu-18-04-os-on-lenovo-thinkpad-l480-lap)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417219/lenovo-y720-keyboard-backlight-extreme-cooling-on-arch-linux
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=240698
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Lenovo/comments/cc1r65/question_lenovo_y720_keyboard_backlight_linux/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/chhat3/turn_keyboard_backlight/
- [cannot turn on keyboard backlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644410/cannot-turn-on-keyboard-backlight)
- [Keyboard backlight Ubuntu 18.10 not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086070/keyboard-backlight-ubuntu-18-10-not-working)
- [No keyboard backlighting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586210/no-keyboard-backlighting)
- [Dell keyboard backlight is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076393/dell-keyboard-backlight-is-not-working)
- [How to light up back-lit keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13886/how-to-light-up-back-lit-keyboard)
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2411163

Comment: One thing to add to your long list of things you already tried perhaps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/383501/enable-the-keyboard-backlights-on-supported-lenovo-e-g-carbon-x1-with-command

Answer (score 0):

I made a software that controls the Lenovo Legion Y720 keyboard backlight.

https://github.com/Izurii/Lenovo-Y720-KB-LED-Driver

It's made for Linux and right now it's working with Ubuntu 20.04

[Lenovo Y720 KB Controller Releases](https://github.com/Izurii/Lenovo-Y720-KB-Led-Controller/releases)

You can download and run the latest AppImage and change the keyboard settings or you can download de DEB package and install using `sudo dpkg -i package-name.deb` in a terminal, the software starts at login so you don't need to open every time you restart your PC, and the global hotkey <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> (the same used in Lenovo Nerve Center) is working.